# Send value as argument to a dynamically assigned controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-controller

I'm trying to reproduce the modal view of [AngularUI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) and dialog view of [angular material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.dialog) behavior of assigning a controller dynamically and be able to send values as arguments

I tried to mimic AngularUI code without success:

```
var elem =  document.getElementById('placeholder');
elem.setAttribute('ng-controller', 'ctrl');

var injector = angular.element(elem).injector();
var compile = injector.get('$compile');
var rootScope = injector.get('$rootScope');
var controller = injector.get('$controller');
var ctrlInstance = controller('ctrl', {$scope:rootScope, value:'hello'}); 
var result = compile(elem)(rootScope);
```

It works for dynamically assigning the controller without passing the value. What am I doing wrong?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXKvyb

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the controller on the element. : 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwNgZx?editors=101

Updated method:

```
function setCtrl() {
    var elem =  document.getElementById('placeholder');
    //elem.setAttribute('ng-controller', 'ctrl');
    var eSpan = elem.children[0];
    var eSelect = elem.children[1];
    eSpan.setAttribute('ng-bind', 'name');

    eSelect.setAttribute('ng-options', 'o as o for o in rows');
    eSelect.setAttribute('ng-model', 'selectedValue');

    var injector = angular.element(elem).injector();
    var compile = injector.get('$compile');
    var rootScope = injector.get('$rootScope');
    var controller = injector.get('$controller');
  var result = compile(elem)(rootScope);  
  var ctrlInstance = controller('ctrl', {$scope:rootScope, value:'hello'});

}
```

Also, when getting the select you were doing children[1].children[0] and that was not correct.

I'm guessing that if you set the `ng-controller` on the element, angular also tries to instantiate it but doesn't know where to get the `value` parameter.

**Edit**

And I made the example do what you wanted it to do .. I think :)

Comment: thanks! Just want to amke sure you did what I'm looking for... Is the controller assigned to the element or to the whole app? AFAIK, in the modal/dialog only the view (specific element) has the controller assigned. Am I right?

Comment: the controller is applied to the compiled element ( the one with id placeholder )